# Помогите с пунктуацией при уточняющем обороте!

Tags: пунктуация

*Послу двух сезонов мультсериала, **богатого сюжетными поворотами**, Братство Тофу столкнется с новыми приключениями.*

Там, где выделенный шрифт, нужны ли запятые?

Answer (score 1):

После двух сезонов мультсериала, **богатого сюжетными поворотами,** Братство Тофу столкнется с новыми приключениями.

Обособлен определительный оборот, стоящий после определяемого слова.

Но стилистика предложения мне не кажется корректной.

**Вариант редактирования:** После двух сезонов мультсериала, богатого сюжетными поворотами, зрители увидят новые приключения героев Братства Тофу.

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: Неотредактированная версия выглядит как неудачный перевод с английского.